# how to find closest folder in the command line

Tags: command-line, bash

Suppose the command :`pwd` returns

```
~/Users/MyUser/FolderA/FolderB
```

I want to write a script where I don't know in advance that I am in `FolderB`, as I can be in `FolderA` or even some other external folder.

My script resides in `FolderB` and I want to find a folder with a specific name `(FolderC)` that resides in `FolderA` alongside `FolderB`

If i search for `find ~ iname "FolderC"` i find all sorts of results that I do not want.
I want only the 1 closest possible directory with that name to my script.

What is the line that will help me find it ?

Comment: I think the find your looking for is "find .. inane "FolderC"' using .. will start find in the directory above current.  Whereas your ~ starts find at your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use the absolute path instead of the relative one.

Instead of ~/... Use /home/... (or C:/... for Windows). This avoids the difficultly in finding the file relative to your location.

Comment: exactly what i do not want to do. this script is to be run on multiple computers

Comment: @LenaBru Ok. you didn't put that in the question, though.

Comment: i didnt have to, the question is asking to find an anonymous folder....  ;)

Answer (score 0):

> My script resides in FolderB and I want to find a folder with a
>   specific name (FolderC) that resides in FolderA alongside FolderB

First you need to find [the directory that your script is in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in).  Then, you need to go up one directory and look for FolderB:

```
dir=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
folderc="$dir/../FolderC"
```

#### Answer for revised question

> I do not know if FolderC resides directly above the script, it may be 2
>   3 or even more directories up, ...

This searches for FolderC through all parent directories up to the root directory:

```
dir=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )    
while echo dir=$dir; [ $dir != / ] && dir=$(dirname "$dir")
do
    b="$dir/FolderC"
    [ -d "$b" ] && break
    false
done || echo "Fail no such directory"
echo "The nearest FolderC is $b"
```

Comment: I don't want to cd into the folder, I want its absolute path without cd, how do i get that?

Comment: I do not know if FolderC resides directly above the script, it may be 2 3 or even more directories up, this is why i said "the closest", meaning look until you find first result

Comment: (1) Sorry for the confusion: the `cd` command is run only within a subshell.  When the assignment of `dir` completes, you are back in the parent shell and the `cd` is gone.  If you try it, you will see that `cd` has no lasting effect.  (2) Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @LenaBru See updated answer for a script that searches through parent directories.

Comment: @LenaBru Did this answer your question?